# Linebreak after each character

Tags: php, html, character, line-breaks

What PHP code would be easiest to use if I want to create a new linebreak after each character.
Lets say that I have this string "hello world!". Now what I wan't to do is to make it look like this:

> h
>
> e
>
> l
>
> l
>
> o
>
> w
>
> o
>
> r
>
> l
>
> d
>
> !

What kind of a code should I use. I only now the linebreak codes and not a code for space between the characters. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you want actually 2 linebreaks, not one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo implode("\n\n",str_split("Hello world"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 0; $i<strlen($str); $i++)
{
    $newstr .= substr ($str,$i,1).chr(YOURDESIREDCHAR);
}
```

You can lookup the value for chr here: http://www.asciitable.com/

For linebreak(s) you can just add "\n" instead of chr(...)

Answer (score 0):

If the output shall be HTML simply add a break after each character.

```
function splitChars( $str )
{
    $out;

    for ( $i = 0; i < strlen( $str ); $i++ )
        $out .= $str{$i} . '<br />';

    return $out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "Hello World";
$result = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
     $result .= $str[$i] . "\n";
}
echo $result;
```